# Why coffeescript include return code in function

Tags: coffeescript

I'm trying to understand why my coffeescript compiled into unexpected js code, where return statement included into function.

```
class Smthg
  ...
  _askAgreement: (callback) =>
    @$(@aggrementModalSelector).foundation('reveal', 'open')
    @$(document).on('opened.fndtn.reveal','[data-reveal]', () =>
      console.log 'opened'
    )
```

compiled into

```
BundleToOrderActionButtonView.prototype._askAgreement = function(callback) {
  this.$(this.aggrementModalSelector).foundation('reveal', 'open');
  return this.$(document).on('opened.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', (function(_this) {
    return function() {
      return console.log('opened');
    };
  })(this));
};
```

so why this:

```
console.log 'opened'
```

became this:

```
    return function() {
      return console.log('opened');
    };
```

when I was expecting this:

```
return console.log('opened');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the fat arrow (`=>`), which force the embedding of the `this` object.

It allows you to access `this` as if you were outside the function.

Using the regular arrow `->`, it does not generate the extra function.

Comment: () => 
will became to this:
function(_this)

Comment: I don't understand your comment? replace `() =>` by `() ->`

Comment: Also, at http://coffeescript.org/ using the tab `Try CoffeeScript`, you have an instant side-to-side compiler, which will help you see exactly what becomes of the modifications you make in the CoffeeScript.

Comment: () => 
will became to this one:
function(_this)
but why return statement was included into function?

Comment: @FrankovskyiBogdan because the third argument of this.$(document).on expects a function. A function is returned from the closure and the value of 'this' is scoped to the closure allowing you to use within any code in the closure.

Comment: @FrankovskyiBogdan: it is an immediatly invoked function to wrap the `this` object into the context of the code executed in that function. Also the parameter to `on` needs to be a function. So here we have a function immediately invoked that returns another function.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to write functions in coffeescript

1) Using the single arrow syntax: () ->

2) Using the fat arrow syntax: () =>

When using 2, it is used to bind it to the current value of 'this'. So what this will do is to create a self-executing function closure (IIFE http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression ) passing in the current value of 'this' to the closure. You can then use 'this' inside anything within the closure and it will be what you expect.

In your case, you do not need to use the 'this' value so you can just change your function declaration to the single arrow syntax and it should work ok.